# Send file to the server with Retrofit and WebKitFormBoundary in PartMap

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I have a query generated by the postman to send files and some info to my server. It works fine in my program.

```
  MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,
                "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"C:\\testFile.doc\"\r\nContent-Type: application/msword\r\n\r\n\r\n" +
                        "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"id\"\r\n\r\n7\r\n" +
                        "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\n3\r\n" +
                        "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"note\"\r\n\r\nafejhejfh\r\n" +
                        "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"list[0][id]\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n" +
                        "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"list[0][is_checked]\"\r\n\r\n0\r\n" +
                        "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"list[0][filename]\"; filename=\"C:\\test.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");
```

Retrofit method:

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json", "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"})
@POST("api/save")
Call<SaveResponse> save(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                                   @Body RequestBody map);
```

First-time faced with webkitformboundary and need to change above sample to dynamically created Partmap. Because need to add some parameters in a cycle from another list. 
I tried to generate partmap with something like below example and add "WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" to headers like wrote in the api documentation

```
  --header 'Authorization: {{authorization}}' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
```

Below code return 422 error from the server

Query Map.

```
Map<String, RequestBody> requestMap = new HashMap<>();

RequestBody file = null;
if (file != null) {
    file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/msword"), testFile);
    requestMap.put("filename", file);
}

RequestBody id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "18");
RequestBody type = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "3");
RequestBody notes = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), notesTextArea.getText());
RequestBody list0id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "1");
RequestBody list0is_checked = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "0");


RequestBody pdfFilename = null;
if (pdfFile != null) {
    pdfFilename  = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), pdfFile);
    requestMap.put("list[0][filename]", pdfFilename );
}

requestMap.put("file", file);
requestMap.put("id", id);
requestMap.put("type", type);
requestMap.put("notes", notes);
requestMap.put("list[0]id", list0id);
requestMap.put("list[0]is_checked", list0is_checked);
```

retrofit method:

```
  @Multipart
    @Headers({"Accept: application/json", "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"})
    @POST("api/save")
    Call<SaveResponse> save(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                                       @PartMap Body map);
```

So need any help to understand how I can put WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW and other needed info to my Partmap.

Thanks in advance for any help

p.s. Happy new year coders )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolve this problem in this way

Request to my server. request without header  "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"" which described in API documentation.

```
 @Multipart
    @Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
    @POST("api/save")
    Call<SaveResponse> save(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                                       @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map,
                                       @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files);
```

Dynamically fill our query

```
  private void fillQuery() {

        fileListPart = new ArrayList<>();
        MultipartBody.Part filePart = null;
        if (mainFile != null) {
            if (mainFile.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename", mainFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), mainFile));
            } else if (mainFile.getName().endsWith(".doc") || mainFile.getName().endsWith(".docx")) {
                filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename", mainFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/msword"), mainFile));
            }
            fileListPart.add(filePart);
        }

        requestBodyMap = new HashMap<>();
        RequestBody id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "id");
        RequestBody type = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "type");
        RequestBody notes = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "notes");

        requestBodyMap.put("id", id);
        requestBodyMap.put("type", type);
        requestBodyMap.put("notes", notes);

        for (int i = 0; i < dynamicCollectionWirhParameters.size(); i++) {
            String prefix = "list[";
            String checkIdParameter = "][id]";
            String checkIsCheckedParameter = "][is_checked]";
            String checkFileParameter = "][filename]";

            RequestBody checklist_id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "2");//id
            RequestBody is_checked = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "1"); // server convert 1 and 0 to boolean value
            requestBodyMap.put(prefix + i + checkIdParameter, checklist_id);
            requestBodyMap.put(prefix + i + checkIsCheckedParameter, is_checked);

            if (dynamicCollectionFileCollection.get(i) != null) {
                File tempFile = dynamicCollectionFileCollection.get(i);
                filePart = null;
                if (tempFile.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(prefix + i + checkFileParameter, dynamicCollectionFileCollection.get(i).getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), dynamicCollectionFileCollection.get(i)));
                } else if (dynamicCollectionFileCollection.get(i).getName().endsWith(".doc") || dynamicCollectionFileCollection.get(i).getName().endsWith(".docx")) {
                    filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(prefix + i + checkFileParameter, dynamicCollectionFileCollection.get(i).getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/msword"), dynamicCollectionFileCollection.get(i)));
                }
                fileListPart.add(filePart);
            }
        }

    }
```

And send our datas to the server

```
private void saveDatas() {
        fillQuery();

        Call<SaveResponse> sendDatasCall = DependenciesStorage.getRetrofitService().save(
                DependenciesStorage.getAuthorizationKey(),
                requestBodyMap, fileListPart);

        sendDatasCall.enqueue(new Callback<SaveResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SaveResponse> call, Response<SaveResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                  } else {

                 }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SaveResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Looks easy ) But i spend almost two days to find it